# Attached devices change /dev/sd value

Tags: linux, mount, dev

I have a script which auto mounts my Windows partition based on `UUID`,

**reason**: my attached devices change their `/dev/sd` value.

After booting up, my external hard drive might take on `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`,

What causes these values to change?

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/sdX` nodes are *not* supposed to be numbered always the same. They are added as and when the system "sees" them appear. If two devices take about the same time to start up, there may be a kind of race condition in the attribution of device nodes.

Your method is the good one. One may as well use label, id, or hardware path, see

```
ls /dev/disk/by-*
```